# In Windows forms application location of controls changed after adding this control on form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, position

I am developing a Windows Forms application using Visual Studio 2010 and C#. I have created one user control to show a detail screen. When I added this user control on another form or user control in panel container then controls positions are changed. I used the doc property, but still see this issue.

```
PanelCancelledConainer.Controls.Clear();
InquiryDetailsCls.InquiryID = Convert.ToInt32(GridInquiry.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
CtrlInqDetails inqDetails = new CtrlInqDetails(InquiryDetailsCls.InquiryID, 1);
inqDetails.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
PanelCancelledConainer.Controls.Add(inqDetails);
```

What can I do so that user controls look as they do in design mode?

Images added from Comments:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Without seeing the difference it is hard to tell, can you post a link to some screen shots so we can see what is happening. I will add them to your question if you do it.

Comment: Please find below screenshot of user control design view http://www.dishagroup.in/images/control1.jpg and next is screenshot of user control after consuming in another form http://www.dishagroup.in/images/control2.jpg spacing in text box and label is increased and entire form view is disturbed.

Answer (score 0):

try to set index position of your usercontrol on the container that is:

```
PanelCancelledConainer.Controls.SetChildIndex(inqDetails, 0);
```

you will be sure that it was the first child.

Comment: This will not help, Please find below screenshot of user control design view http://www.dishagroup.in/images/control1.jpg and next is screenshot of user control after consuming in another form http://www.dishagroup.in/images/control2.jpg spacing in text box and label is increased and entire form view is disturbed.

Comment: I do like you a user control with tabcontrol and it works when I set it on windows form. To have your problem, I modify font of container and it modify font of user control so set the same font in your container than in your user container and it will work ;-)

Comment: I my scenario I created user control (say DetailControl) containing tab control and this DetailControl is placed on another user control. The size of DetailControl is equal to container where I place. Still it will increase spacing in label and text box as given in above images.

Comment: in your screenshot we can see that titles appear with different font (in first no bold, in second bold and title are bigger)

Comment: I changed font but still issue persist, when control is used then spacing between label and text box increased and due to this complete form is not displayed

Comment: try to first use only your detailcontrol directly on a form (so no setting in another user control) and tell us if you have already the same problem thank ;-)